# Unable to install Mysql

Tags: yum, mysql

When I install mysql on my Centos, I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Is there any problem with yum?

Comment: If you hit that path with a browser, it says:  "Bad repo - not in list - SCL install fasttrack contrib updates os extras centosplus cr addons".   I would treat that as an additional clue, it sounds like instructions.   The "repo=os_error" looks like some bit of logic in yum is constructing a URL, and a piece of the logic can't figure out the repo name.

Comment: Okay..So what should I do now ?

Comment: It's been a while since I used yum, sorry.  But there is a repo list (I think it's in /etc/repos.d (?) ) and it's probably wise to start reading the man pages and googling to understand how yum finds and updates repos.   Or... wait until someone who is yum-smarter than me comes  along! :)

Comment: @RohitSingh, are you behind a proxy server? Please check if you can connect from the terminal with telnet command: `telnet centos.org 80`

Comment: Yes,I am using proxy server 192.168.1.1.But I am unable to run the command telnet centos.org 80 which says "command not found"

Comment: Actually,My internet is working good. When I ping google.com by command ping google.com. It gives the following details:

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.200.139) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sa-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.200.139): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=102 ms
64 bytes from sa-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.200.139): icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=93.3 ms
64 bytes from sa-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.200.139): icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 time=94.1 ms
64 bytes from sa-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.200.139): icmp_seq=4 ttl=46 time=92.3 ms
64 bytes from sa-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.200.139): icmp_seq=5 ttl=46 time=113 ms