# problem regarding YUM

Tags: yum

I have a problem with my Centos 6. Actually, I am trying to run any command like `yum update` or `yum upgrade` or `yum install mysqlmysql-server`. Everytime, I got an error below:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Comment: check your internet connectivity

Comment: There is no problem in my internet connection .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix "cannot find a valid baseurl for repo" errors on CentOS?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22924/how-can-i-fix-cannot-find-a-valid-baseurl-for-repo-errors-on-centos)

Comment: @Networker This is not really a duplicate of that question, since there obviously is net connectivity here -- the server returned a **403 Forbidden** (which is not a firewall issue, either) -- resulting in a different PYCURL ERROR.

Comment: Are you using a proxy server? Maybe that's confusing things.  Also, try `yum clean all` followed by `yum update`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install Mysql](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148006/unable-to-install-mysql)